# Populating a TextBox based on selection in ComboBox

Tags: vbscript, combobox, textbox, outlook, outlook-2010

all! I'll try to be as detailed as possible in describing my predicament. I have a little background knowledge in Visual Basic, but none really in VBA or VBscript in Outlook 2010.
I'm working with Outlook 2010. I created a custom form (this is my first time). I have a combo box named ComboBox1 and a text box named TextBox1. I am trying to auto-populate TextBox1 with a number based on the selection made from ComboBox1 (ex. I select Value 1 from ComboBox1 and TextBox1 populates with 124).
I made an attempt using this code in the Visual Basic Editor (VBA version 7.0):

```
Sub popBox()
If ComboBox1 = "Value 1" Then
TextBox1 = "124"
End If
End Sub
```

My question is what am I doing wrong? Should I be using the VBscript editor, or is using VBA the proper thing to do?
Is what I am asking even possible? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This morning was a great one! I discovered the solution to my problem. In case anyone has this problem in the future, here is what I came up with:

```
Sub Item_CustomPropertyChange(ByVal Aircraft)

Set myInspector = Item.GetInspector
Set FormPage = myInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Form")
Set Aircraft = FormPage.Controls("Aircraft")
Set PartNumber = FormPage.Controls("PartNumber")
    Select Case Aircraft.Value
        Case "Value 1"
            PartNumber.Value = "124"
        Case "Value 2"
            PartNumber.Value = "125"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click your form and choose "View Code". Now, you should be able to choose from a drop-down menu *just* above the text entry section of the code editor. Choose "ComboBox1", then from the adjacent drop-down menu select "Change".

The editor should create a routine for you called "Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()". Enter the following:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Select Case ComboBox1.Value
    Case "Value 1"
      TextBox1.Caption = "124"
    Case Else
      TextBox1.Caption = ""
  End Select
End Sub
```

You can also paste the above code (as long as your combo box is called "ComboBox1" and your textbox "TextBox1") in the code for the form, and achieve the same result. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Thank you for the response!
I tried that code, and it didn't seem to work for me.
Both the combo box and text box are bound, if that makes a difference.
ComboBox1 is bound to Aircraft and TextBox1 is bound to PartNumber.

I know I have to do something in VBscript with the Item_CustomPropertyChange(ByVal Aircraft) (maybe), but I'm not quite sure where to go after that.

Comment: Sorry to post twice in one night, but I forgot to insert the code I worked out today (but doesn't work).

My customized tab is named 'Form'

With much research today, I came up with this:

Sub Item_CustomPropertyChange(ByVal Aircraft)

Set myInspector = Item.GetInspector
Set FormPage = myInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Form")
Set Aircraft = FormPage.Controls("Aircraft")
Set PartNumber = FormPage.Controls("PartNumber")
 Select Case Aircraft.Value
  Case "Value 1"
   PartNumber.Value = "124"
  Case "Value 2"
   PartNumber.Value = "125"
 End Select
End Sub